# How to use decode or case function to build a condition base on the result of two records?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say if I search by a key, it returns 2 records with 2 different values for each record.
It will return value 'A' and value 'B' for the 1st and 2nd records respectively.

```
ID VALUE
1   A
1   B
```

If the returned records contains 'A' and 'B' then I want to change all their value to 'C'.
If the returned record only contains 'A' or 'B' then i don't want to change to 'C'
How do i use the decode or case function to do that?

I tried `(Case when value in('A','B') then 'C' else value end)` 
but it also changes the records that only returns either 'A' or 'B' to 'C'

So basically if my result are like this :

```
   ID VALUE
    1   A
    1   B
```

I want it to be like this

```
   ID VALUE
    1   C
    1   C
```

If the result is

```
   ID VALUE   or   ID VALUE
    1   A           1   B
    1   A           1   B
```

Then don't implement the above conversion rule.

Edit for clarity

select id, value from t1
where id =123
gives me below

```
ID VALUE
 1   A
 1   B
```

I want a condition that uses the value of the two records--change the value to 'C' only when clm1.value=A and clm2.value=B

something like below but it does not work.

```
  select id,
           case when value ='A' and value ='B' then 'C' else value end
    from t1
    where id=123
```

Sorry for the confusion. 
Thanks

Comment: Looking at it, not enough information for me to know exactly what you want to do.  add some more code of what you have already tried and explain what it is doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use case/decode in this situation, you are comparing across records, not just columns in a single record.  Not sure if this is possible.  Maybe with an analytic/window function.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
create table csm (id int, value varchar(5))

insert into csm (id,value)
SELECT 1,'A' UNION
SELECT 1,'B' UNION
SELECT 2,'A' UNION
SELECT 3,'B' UNION
SELECT 4,'A' UNION
SELECT 4,'B' UNION
SELECT 4,'D'

SELECT t.id
 , case when tsub.TotalTimes=2 AND tsub.NumTimes=2 THEN 'C' ELSE t.value END as Value
FROM csm t
JOIN (
    SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN value IN ('A','B') THEN value END) AS NumTimes
        , COUNT(DISTINCT value) TotalTimes
    FROM csm
    GROUP BY id
) AS tsub ON t.id=tsub.id
```

I get the following output:

```
1   C
1   C
2   A
3   B
4   A
4   B
4   D
```

The subquery finds out the number of times A and B occur for that id, and then your case statement checks if that value is 2, and if so changes it to C.

Comment: I inserted another record, (1,'D'). Ran the query, it turned all three into 'C'.

Comment: @JohnD I edited the query where there are more than 2 records possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a perfect match for an analytic function:

```
with v_data(id, value) as (
  select 1, 'A' from dual union all
  select 1, 'B' from dual union all
  select 2, 'A' from dual union all
  select 3, 'B' from dual union all
  select 3, 'B' from dual
)
select 
  v1.*, 
  (case 
   when v1.cnt_distinct > 1 then 'C' 
   else v1.value end) 
  as new_value
from ( 
  select 
    id, 
    value, 
    count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt_overal,
    count(distinct value) over (partition by id) as cnt_distinct
  from v_data) 
v1
```

This computes the number of distinct values for each ID (using `count(distinct...`) and then replaces the values with `C` if the number of distinct values is larger than 1.